# Verification of Proof that if N is a normal subgroup and H is any subgroup HN={hn| h in H and n in N} is a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

My proof is as follows:

I only have question for the closure portion.

Closure: Let h1, h2 be in H and n1, n2 be in N.  Since N is normal we can say $Nh_2=h_2N$.
This also means $n_1h_2=h_2n_3$
So $h_1n_1h_2n_2$=$h_1h_2n_3n_2$ and this is in HN.

I probably didn't learn proving subgroups as well as I needed to, but why do we need to set a new $n_3$ in the second line?

I have to also show that HN is the smalls subgroup containing N and H.  I guessed that it is because there is a binary operation for hn?  Is that right and why is that true?

Comment: To answer your first question: When we say $Nh_2 = h_2N$, we mean an equality of SETS. Meaning $\{h_2n : n \in N\} = \{nh_2: n \in N\}$. However, this doesn't mean that $nh_2 = h_2n$ necessarily. Thus if we take some $n_1 \in N$, then $n_1h_2 \in h_2N$ means that $n_1h_2 = h_2n_3$ for some $n_3\in N$.

Comment: and in answer to your second question, any group $G$ containing $H$ and $N$ must contain at least all the products $hn$, and these make up all of $HN$ so $HN \subset G$

Comment: Notice also that $N$ and $H$ are both subgroups of this group since for $e \in H$, we have $\{en \in HN: n \in N\}= N \leq HN$ and since $H$ and $N$ share the identity, $e \in N$ and $\{he \in HN: h \in H\} = H \leq HN$.