# Prove that $HN = NH$ and that this set is a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $H, N$ be subgroups of a group $G$, with $N$ normal. Prove that $HN = NH$ and that this set is a subgroup.

**My Solution:** Since $N$ normal, then $K\cap N$ is also normal subgroup of $K$, $K$ is a subgroup of $G$.

$HN=\{hn:h\in H,n\in N\}$ and $NH=\{nh:h\in H,n\in N\}$

Now,

$$HN=\{h(H\cap N):h\in H\}\cup\{h(H^c\cap N):h\in H\}\\=\{h(H\cap N):h\in H\}\cup\{h(\cup_{a\notin H}(aH)\cap N):h\in H\}\\=\{h(H\cap N):h\in H\}\cup\{\cup_{a\notin H}h(aH\cap N):h\in H\}\\=\{(H\cap N)h:h\in H\}\cup\{\cup_{a\notin H}(aH\cap N)h:h\in H\}=NH$$

**Proof of being subgroup:** (Although this part can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999287/verification-of-proof-that-if-n-is-a-normal-subgroup-and-h-is-any-subgroup-hn-h).)

1. $HN\subset G$
2. $h_1,h_2\in H$, $n_1,n_2\in N$, then $h_1n_1h_2n_2=h_1h_2n_3n_2\in HN$, where $n_3=h^{-1}_2n_1h_2\in N$
3. $1\in HN$.
4. $h\in H,n\in N$, then $hn\in HN$. Now $(hn)^{-1}=n^{-1}h^{-1}\in NH=HN$

Then $HN$ is a subgroup of $G.\space\space\space\blacksquare$

Comment: Why do you assert that $h_1n_1h_2n_2=h_1h_2n_1n_2$? And that $h_1n_1h_1^{-1}n_1^{-1}=h_1n_1n_1^{-1}h_1^{-1}$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos is it ok now? And what about the first part?

Comment: You must say what is $n_3$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks. Is first part ok, or could it be proved in shorter way?

Comment: Try to prove that $ HN\subseteq NH$ by choosing an element $ x\in HN $ and showing that belongs to $NH $. Your proof is not easy to read (at least for me).

Comment: Thanks @Xam I got that answer(see answer by José Carlos Santos)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second part is correct (after the editions). The first part can be simplified: if $h\in H$ and $n\in N$, then $hn=hnh^{-1}h\in NH$, since $N$ is normal. Therefore $HN\subset NH$ and a similar argument proves that $NH\subset HN$.

Comment: Thanks... I have to think more easily, I think.