# Let G be a group and $ N \trianglelefteq G, H\le G, then \left\langle N\cup H\right\rangle =NH$ so $NH=HN$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Let G be a group and $ N  \trianglelefteq G, H\le G, then \left\langle N\cup H\right\rangle =NH$
>   so $NH=HN$

We proved this in class in the following way:
$\forall n\in N, n\in \left\langle N\cup H\right\rangle, \forall h \in H, h\in \left\langle N\cup H\right\rangle $

$\therefore nh\in \left\langle N\cup H\right\rangle $

$\therefore NH\subseteq \left\langle N\cup H\right\rangle$

And $1\in N\quad and\quad 1\in H$ $\qquad\implies$
 $
N\subseteq NH \& H\subseteq NH$

(until here I am okay with the reasoning)

Thus, if we can show that NH is a subgroup of G, then $NH=\left\langle N\cup H\right\rangle  (WHY?) $

Then we proved $NH\leq G$ $\qquad$ (here I am also Okay.)

And concluded $NH\trianglelefteq G$

Firstly I didn't understand how $NH$'s being subgroup of G implies $NH=\left\langle N\cup H\right\rangle$

And secondly 
$NH=\left\langle N\cup H\right\rangle$ $\qquad$ is equivalent to $NH=HN$

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373560/prove-that-hn-nh-and-that-this-set-is-a-subgroup?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thus, if we can show that $NH$ is a subgroup of $G$, then  $NH=⟨N∪H⟩$(WHY?)**

you prove that $N\cup H\subseteq NH$, by definition $\left<N\cup H\right>$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $N\cup H$, hence if $NH$ is a group it follows that $\left<N\cup H\right>\subseteq NH$. The other direction is not hard so I'll leave it to you.

**And secondly $NH=⟨N∪H⟩$ is equivalent to  $NH=HN$**

you can repeat your arguments and prove that $HN=\left<N\cup H\right>$ and so $HN=\left<N\cup H\right>=NH$.

Comment: So basically will I reverse the order ? Starting "$\forall h\in H, h\in \left\langle N\cup H\right\rangle, \forall n \in N, n\in \left\langle N\cup H\right\rangle $ $\qquad$                                         
 $\qquad$ $\therefore hn\in \left\langle N\cup H\right\rangle \qquad$ " $\qquad$ and continue in this manner till the end then show $HN=\left\langle N\cup H\right\rangle ?$

Comment: yes exactly....